# Laravel, can't log a user by id and then redirect him

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel 5.2. I'd like to log a user by his id and then redirect him to the dashboard but it's not working.

I did this:

```
$result = Auth::loginUsingId($id);
var_dump($result->toArray());
```

and the result is fine. It returns the object user with all his data.

But after redirecting the user to the dashboard with **return redirect()->route('dashboard');** it send me to login page!

I discover then that **Auth::user()** returns **null** !

What shall i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authentication needs sessions and for sessions to work you need to use the `web` middleware. So the routes that need working sessions should be defined like this:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Routes that need sessions go here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $redirectTo as stated in the documentation, if you get into login again Auth wasn't successful, perhaps something related with session or cookies, or just a bad time configuration. Try `Auth::loginUsingId($id, true);` then.